# how to download a csv file returned by post request made to a REST API

Tags: angularjs, csv, download, postman

**Edit:**

html file:

```
<button data-ng-click="$ctrl.toCSV()">ToCSV</button>
```

code in controller:

```
$scope.toCSV = function () {
   var sampleJson = {"key1": ["val1", "val2"], "key2": "valKey2", "key3": "valKey3"};
   // the service forms and returns the url string
   var url = vm.originUrl + sampleService.getCSVDetails(id, false, "csv").url;
   var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post" style="display:none;">' +
            '<input type="text/json" name="jsonData" value="' + sampleJson + '" />' + '</form>');
        $('body').append(form);
        form.submit();
    };
```

I am not able to understand where I could be going wrong, I checked a lot of solutions posted. The response that I am getting when I pass the same using postman is:

```
cache-control →no-store, no-cache=set-cookie
content-disposition →attachment; filename=SampleDetails.csv
content-encoding →gzip
content-language →en-US
content-length →767
content-type →application/octet-stream
date →Wed, 25 Oct 2017 15:13:51 GMT
expires →Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
pragma →no-cache
x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by →Servlet/3.1
```

I am just not sure how to set this up so that the it gets downloaded in the browser on clicking the text 'ToCSV'. Right now it just open in a new blank page instead of download, although in postman I am able to get the content of the file.

Any suggestions how to bundle the json data and hit the URL via post method...?

Thanks!

Comment: one possible reason could be that I am trying to use window.location using POST request... I don't think that works... any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I used [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to download my pdf files.

```
function downloadPdf(id) {
    myServiceToGetFile(id).then(function(response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/octet-stream"});
        //change download.pdf to the name of whatever you want your file to be
        fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'fileName.pdf');
   }
}
```

and the service looks like this:

```
function myServiceToGetFile(id) {
    return $http.get(
        baseUrl + '/link/to/pdf/' + id, 
        {responseType: "arraybuffer"}); // must add this to work
}
```

PS: We had to put the library in a service, because of some minification issues.

Comment: Hi @Denisa Lavinia Profir Unfortunately I don't think I am supposed to use any 3rd party libraries here, but thanks.. I'll still keep this option as a last resort :)

Comment: Is there any way I can use form or anything else to redirect to the required url.. instead of windows.location along with the data?

Comment: You can add the content as service.

Comment: I tried, but only this worked for me. And as you, in postman worked fine, but from the browser nothing :(